Table not formatting properly in report - runs off the side of the page
So I'm having issues with the formatting on this table. I would like it to look more like this table if possible:

However, it won't set up this format no matter how much I try, whether with changing the text size or line width. It always ends with odd formatting like this:

The set up in main.tex is here:
\documentclass[12pt,twosided]{report}

% Packages needed
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % To obtain English text with the blindtext package
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx} %For inputing images
\graphicspath{{images/}} %bringing in pics from folder
\usepackage[a4paper,total={175mm,257mm},top=20mm,bottom=20mm,bindingoffset=2mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setlength\headheight{14pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt}
%Formatting stuff

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{Trail Blazers - PDR}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\small\thepage} %Specifies page number location
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\small Section \thechapter}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{Team 40}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\RBox[1]{%
  \tikz\node[draw,rounded corners,align=center,] {#1};%
} 

%gGets rid of Chapter #... and adding number infront of chapter title
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter{ }}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}

And this is the code for the table itself:
\section{Level 1 Requirements}
% Setting top and bottom padding for cells
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
% Adjusting row height
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}  
% Adjusting column padding
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}  

%% Spec Table

% Level 1
\begin{longtable}{|p{2.2cm}|p{2.7cm}|p{7cm}|p{2.4cm}|p{3cm}|}
 \hline
 \rowcolor{YellowGreen}\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Fire Support Specification Table}} \\
 \hline
 % Sub Titles
 \rowcolor{lightgray} \textbf{ID} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Requirement} & \textbf{Verifying Method} & \textbf{Source} \\
 \hline
 \hline

 % Content
 \raggedright L1-ED1
 & \raggedright Weight & \raggedright Shall weigh within a range of 0.1-1 kg & Scale & Preliminary \\ \hline
 
 \raggedright L1-FD3 & \raggedright Air Filtering & \raggedright Air Filter shall capture particle sizes of .4-7 micrometers & Ruler \ Calipers & EPA 2009 \\ \hline
 
 \raggedright L1-FD5 & \raggedright Muttonchops & \raggedright Device shall create air current that displaces heavier particles in the smoke. & Test & Param \\ \hline
 
 \raggedright L1-SS2-0 & \raggedright Heat Resistance & \raggedright Fabric and all materials used in garment construction shall not drip, melt, separate, ignite, or char. & Excel & Sprod, Owen \\ \hline
 
 \raggedright 3.1 & \raggedright Material Strength & \raggedright Product should have an ultimate tensile strength of 2 GPa & UTM & Ford, David \\ \hline
 
 \raggedright 3.2 & \raggedright Material Heat Resistance & \raggedright The material shall resist heat up to 400$^\circ$F & Certified & Ford, David \\ \hline
 
 \raggedright 3.3 & \raggedright Power Source & \raggedright The product should produce 10 amps of current for up to 10 hours & Oscilloscope & Flores, Cristina \\ \hline
 
 \raggedright 3.5 & \raggedright Lifespan & \raggedright Should function for 10 hours before battery supply is depleted & User & Ford, David \\ \hline
 
 \raggedright 4.1 & \raggedright Market & \raggedright Product should be desired by fire stations & Research & Team 40 \\ \hline
 
 \raggedright 4.2 & \raggedright Scope & \raggedright Prototype shall be completed within two semesters & Performance Goals & Team 40 \\ \hline
 
 \raggedright 5.1 & \raggedright User Health (Dehydration) & \raggedright Shall keep user's serum osmolality below 295 mOsm/kg & Osmometer & Flores, Cristina \\ \hline
 
 \raggedright 5.2 & \raggedright User Health (Heat Stroke) & \raggedright User's body temperature shall be kept below 104$^\circ$F & Thermometer & French, Kate \\ \hline
 
 \raggedright 5.3 & \raggedright User Health (Stroke) & \raggedright BPM will remain within a healthy range for age when doing moderate/vigorous exercise (refer to notes for specific heart rates by age) & Holter Monitor & Flores, Cristina \\ \hline
 
 \raggedright 5.4 & \raggedright User Health & \raggedright User's oxygen intake during exercise should range from 40-100 L/min of air over a 14 hr period & Pulse Oximeter & Lamb, John \\ \hline
 
 \raggedright 5.5 & \raggedright User Interface & \raggedright Product should be usable after 30 minutes of training & User & Lamb, John \\ \hline
 
 \caption{Preliminary Product Specification Table\label{long}}\\
 
\end{longtable}
\vspace{5mm}


My main suggestion would be to switch from a longtable setup to an xltabular setup. The xltabular package and its eponymous environment combine the capabilities of the longtable (let a table contain page breaks) and tabularx (ability to set a target width -- usually, but not necessarily, `\textwidth) packages.
I would also suggest (a) reducing the value of \tabcolsep to 3pt; (b) getting rid of all \raggedright instructions in the table, since you're loading the ragged2e package with the option document; (c) changing the column type of the first column from p to l; and (d) reducing the width of the final column from 3cm to 2.5cm.
With these changes in place, the table will fit on a single page.
Optionally, you may want to load the siunitx package and start using its \unit and \qty macros to typeset scientific quantities and their associated units.

\documentclass[12pt,twosided]{report}

% Packages needed
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cellspace}
%%%%\usepackage{tabularx}
%%%%\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xltabular} % <-- new

\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{gensymb}
%%%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{float} % are you sure about this?
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}} %bringing in pics from folder
\usepackage[a4paper,total={175mm,257mm}, 
            top=20mm,bottom=20mm,
            bindingoffset=2mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setlength\headheight{14pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt}

%Formatting stuff

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{Trail Blazers - PDR}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\small\thepage} % Page number location
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\small Section \thechapter}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{Team 40}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\RBox[1]{%
  \tikz\node[draw,rounded corners,align=center,] {#1};%
} 

%%%%\usepackage{titlesec} % don't load packages twice
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]%
  {\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter{ }}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}


%new
\usepackage{calc} % for \widthof macro
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx} % for \qty and \unit macros

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{2} % just for this example

\section{Level 1 Requirements}

% Set top and bottom padding for cells
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
% Adjust row height
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}  
% Adjust column padding
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt} % default: 6pt

%% Spec Table

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|l|p{2.7cm}|X|p{\widthof{Thermometer}}|p{2.5cm}|}

%% headers and footers

\hline
\rowcolor{YellowGreen}
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Fire Support Specification Table}} \\
\hline
% Column titles
\rowcolor{lightgray} 
\textbf{ID} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Requirement} & \textbf{Verifying Method} & \textbf{Source} \\
\hline
\endhead

\caption{Preliminary Product Specification Table\label{long}}\\
\endlastfoot


% Content
 L1-ED1
 & Weight & Shall weigh within a range of 0.1--1 kg & Scale & Preliminary \\ \hline
 
 L1-FD3 & Air Filtering & Air Filter shall capture particle sizes of 0.4--7\,\unit{\micro\meter} & Ruler\newline Calipers & EPA 2009 \\ \hline
 
 L1-FD5 & Muttonchops & Device shall create air current that displaces heavier particles in the smoke. & Test & Param \\ \hline
 
 L1-SS2-0 & Heat Resistance & Fabric and all materials used in garment construction shall not drip, melt, separate, ignite, or char. & Excel & Sprod, Owen \\ \hline
 
 3.1 & Material Strength & Product should have an ultimate tensile strength of \qty{2}{\giga\pascal} & UTM & Ford, David \\ \hline
 
 3.2 & Material Heat Resistance & The material shall resist heat up to 400$^\circ$\,F & Certified & Ford, David \\ \hline
 
 3.3 & Power Source & The product should produce 10 amps of current for up to 10 hours & Oscilloscope & Flores, Cristina \\ \hline
 
 3.5 & Lifespan & Should function for 10 hours before battery supply is depleted & User & Ford, David \\ \hline
 
 4.1 & Market & Product should be desired by fire stations & Research & Team 40 \\ \hline
 
 4.2 & Scope & Prototype shall be completed within two semesters & Performance Goals & Team 40 \\ \hline
 
 5.1 & User Health (Dehydration) & Shall keep user's serum osmolality below 295 mOsm/kg & Osmometer & Flores, Cristina \\ \hline
 
 5.2 & User Health (Heat Stroke) & User's body temperature shall be kept below 104$^\circ$\,F & Thermometer & French, Kate \\ \hline
 
 5.3 & User Health (Stroke) & BPM will remain within a healthy range for age when doing moderate\slash vigorous exercise (refer to notes for specific heart rates by age) & Holter Monitor & Flores, Cristina \\ \hline
 
 5.4 & User Health & User's oxygen intake during exercise should range from 40--100\,\unit{\liter\per\minute} of air over a 14 hr period & Pulse Oximeter & Lamb, John \\ \hline
 
 5.5 & User Interface & Product should be usable after 30 minutes of training & User & Lamb, John \\ \hline

\end{xltabular}

\end{document}


Maybe you liked

I would format your table on above showed way.  Ding so the table caption and column headers appear at each part of table. So it is simpler to know, what is in some column and to which table belongs parts of table.
By use of the longtablr of tabularray package the code is short and clear:
\documentclass[12pt,twosided]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,total={175mm,257mm},
            top=20mm,bottom=20mm,
            headheight=14pt,
            marginparwidth=0pt,
            bindingoffset=2mm]{geometry}

% Packages needed
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}} %bringing in pics from folder
\usepackage{titlesec}


%Formatting stuff
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{Trail Blazers - PDR}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\small\thepage} % Page number location
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\small Section \thechapter}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{Team 40}

%%%%\usepackage{titlesec} % don't load packages twice
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]%
  {\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter{ }}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}

% Packages needed
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray} % <-- new
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol,
         range-phrase= { -- },
         range-units = single, 
         } % for \qty and \unit macros
\SetTblrStyle{contfoot-text}{\footnotesize\itshape}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{2} % just for this example
\section{Level 1 Requirements}
\blindtext[1]


\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Preliminary Product Specification Table},
  label = {long}
                ]{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[l] X[1.1, l] X[2.8, j] X[1.1, l] X[l]},
             cell{1}{1} = {c=5}{c,font=\bfseries, bg=YellowGreen},
                 row{2} = {m, font=\bfseries, bg=lightgray},
             rowsep=3pt,
             rowhead = 2
             }
%
Fire Support Specification Table
    &       &       &       &                       \\
ID  & Title & Requirement   
                    & Verifying Method  
                            & Source                \\
% table body
L1-ED1
    & Weight 
            & Shall weigh within a range of \qtyrange{0.1}{1}{kg}
                    & Scale & Preliminary           \\
L1-FD3 
    & Air Filtering 
            & Air Filter shall capture particle sizes of \qtyrange{0.4}{7}{\micro\meter} 
                    & {Ruler\\ Calipers}
                            & EPA 2009              \\
L1-FD5
    & Muttonchops 
            & Device shall create air current that displaces heavier particles in the smoke. 
                    & Test  & Param                 \\ 
L1-SS2-0 
    & Heat Resistance 
            & Fabric and all materials used in garment construction shall not drip, melt, separate, ignite, or char.
                    & Excel & Sprod, Owen           \\

3.1 & Material Strength
            & Product should have an ultimate tensile strength of \qty{2}{\giga\pascal}
                    & UTM   & Ford, David           \\
3.2 & Material Heat Resistance
            & The material shall resist heat up to \qty{400}{\degree F}
                    & Certified
                            & Ford, David           \\
3.3 & Power Source
            & The product should produce 10 amps of current for up to 10 hours
                    & Oscilloscope
                            & Flores, Cristina      \\
3.5 & Lifespan
            & Should function for 10 hours before battery supply is depleted
                    & User  & Ford, David           \\
4.1 & Market & Product should be desired by fire stations
                    & Research
                            & Team 40               \\
4.2 & Scope & Prototype shall be completed within two semesters
                    & Performance Goals
                            & Team 40               \\
5.1 & User Health (Dehydration)
            & Shall keep user's serum osmolality below 295 mOsm/kg
                    & Osmometer
                            & Flores, Cristina      \\
5.2 & User Health (Heat Stroke)
            & User's body temperature shall be kept below \qty{104}{\degree \,F}
                    & Thermometer
                            & French, Kate          \\
5.3 & User Health (Stroke)
            & BPM will remain within a healthy range for age when doing moderate\slash vigorous exercise (refer to notes for specific heart rates by age)
                    & Holter Monitor
                            & Flores, Cristina      \\
5.4 & User Health
            & User's oxygen intake during exercise should range from \qtyrange{40}{100}{\liter\per\minute} of air over a 14 hr period
                    & Pulse Oximeter    
                            & Lamb, John            \\ 
5.5 & User Interface 
            & Product should be usable after 30 minutes of training 
                    & User  & Lamb, John            \\ 
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}

